# Avoid to rewrite code for activities with the same layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I'd like to run several Activities on my Application;I'd like each Activity to have a Linear Layout and to show an image as heading; basically I'd like every layout to start like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/Grey"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageHeader" android:src="@drawable/tf_header" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/Black" android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>
```

Is it possible not to reapeat this code for each layout? Could I use themes or styles to avoid it? Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes thats possible use the `<include>` tag as described in [Layout Tricks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).

For your example I would add the image as `<include>` and have a `LinearLayout` in each Activity layout xml

Answer (score 0):

One of my apps uses the same xml file for 30 or so classes, i just modify it in code to customize it. That approach may work, just leave every label in the xml blank and set it in the .class